# Logout redirects to a broken page(home URL is omitted)

Tags: options, logout, home-url

I'm using the latest version of WP. I have a problem, where clicking the logout button from the admin panel redirects to a completely broken link:

> http://wp-login.php/?loggedout=true

As you can see, the domain is completely omitted from the link(in my case it's wp.localhost)

I will mention that this local WP site was "cloned" from a remote server, but i made sure to change the "siteurl" and "home" fields in the wp_options table, **and everything else works just fine**

Can somebody tell me, where the problem might be? Is there any other configuration field, that might be relevant to this?

Comment: Have you tried deactivating all plugins and/or switching to a default theme? Have you checked the `wp-config.php` file for special settings like [`WP_SITEURL`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#wp_siteurl)? How about your `.htaccess` file - anything that's suspicious?

Comment: When you cloned the site, did you use a database migration plugin? Just changing those two options in the database isn't usually enough.

Comment: Sally CJ: Deactivating plugins and switching to the default theme didn't help. Also i didn't see anything suspicious in .htaccess or wp-config.php.
WebElaine: I didn't use migration tool. I just exported and imported my WP database. I think i also changed something besides those two options, but i don't remember what. Any ideas?

Comment: "clicking the logout button" - right-click on the button/link and inspect the HTML - does it point to the proper URL? If yes, which button exactly is that (screenshot will help)?

Comment: It's pointing to "http://wp.localhost/wp-login.php?action=logout..."
I think the problem is in the redirecting that occurs AFTER the logout operation was successful, because clicking this link DOES  invalidate the session, and i need to login again. I tried to follow the execution stack using XDEBUG, but didn't manage to pick up any clues...

Comment: same problem here. It is happening on all my recent localhost sites - one of which is a new WordPress install. I assumed it was because of a wordpress update. I've just checked on a localhost site on WP 4.8.10 and it logs out correctly

Comment: Nat, did you also manually "clone" a WP site?

Comment: @sheff2k1 -  some of my sites are clean installs, some of them are cloned with duplicator. same issue on both

Comment: This is insanely weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. It is a bug in WordPress v5.2.3 affecting WordPress in Windows environments. Caused by backslashes in Windows paths that aren't stripped correctly

Details here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/47980

I have tried the patch suggested and can confirm it solves the problem.

replace:

```
$location = '/' . ltrim( $path . '/', '/' ) . $location;
```

with

```
$location = '/' . ltrim( $path . '/', '/\\' ) . $location;
```

in /wp-includes/pluggable.php, line 1404

It says it will be fixed in version 5.2.4